# Integer Linear Programming - Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

I am dealing with a [CVRP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp) with multiple vehicles. I am struggling to come up with a formula for the constraint that each node with a non zero demand must be visited by one vehicle, once.

I am trying to enforce the constraint that if demand is greater than zero, than node visits by all vans is equal to $1$. Would the following suffice?
$$\Large\boxed{max(d_i)\sum_{v\in V}y_i^v \ge d_i}$$

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-routing

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $d_i$ is the demand for node $i$ and $y_i^v$ is a binary decision variable that indicates whether node $i$ is visited by vehicle $v$, the desired constraint is
$$\sum_v y_i^v = 1 \quad \text{for all $i$ such that $d_i>0$}$$